# Android. Alternative way for logging Application Output

Tags: java, android, performance, logging

I'm currently working on an App, which writes millions of lines to logcat (debugging  output). I catch all these Informations (at runtime) by filtering the logoutput (of logcat) and write all the information in a file (redirect locat to a file). Unfortunately this takes very long and therefore the app runs very slow.

Now I wanted to ask, if there is a way, how i could get all these information faster. Is it faster, instead of writing the debugging information to logcat, to directly write the information to a textfile (on the device), or does anyone know a better way to gather these lines more efficient??!.

Thanks for reading,
greetings B.

Comment: Why are you logging millions of lines to log cat? Logging should be kept to a minimum: [http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#log-sparingly](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#log-sparingly)

Comment: Writing my debugging info to logcat was actually never my primary goal, i just wanted a fast and conveniant way to write my infolines to a file. Do you have any idea, how i could acchieve this goal in a more efficient way?!

Comment: Of course logging millions of lines will be slow. It will be slow no matter how you do it. What are you doing that is collecting "millions" of pieces of data in the first place?

Comment: Thats true, but I'm searching for a way, to improve the performace, and therefore i wanted to ask, if anyone could propably tell me a more efficient way.... Is it faster to write my debuggingstring to logcat and then redirect the informations to my logfile (as it already is), or is it faster to perform millions of writing accesses to a file, directly from my Device?

Or is it even faster, if i write all my debugging lines to a string variable in first place and write this variable to my logging file once a while

Answer (score 2):

There exist multiple logging tools. I recommend having a look at [Timber trees](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber).

But please listen on Jake Wharton:

> Every time you log in production, a puppy dies.

Here is a list of logger tools from [awesome-android](https://github.com/JStumpp/awesome-android#logger):

> - [logger](https://github.com/orhanobut/logger) - Simple, pretty and powerful logger for android

- [timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) - A logger with a small, extensible API which provides utility on top of Android's normal Log class.
- [LoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/ihsanbal/LoggingInterceptor) - An OkHttp interceptor which pretty logs request and response data.
- [Bugfender](https://github.com/bugfender/BugfenderSDK-android-sample) - Upload your logs and check them online, specially made for mobile
- [EzyLogger](https://github.com/afiqiqmal/EzyLogger) - Simple Lightweight logger
- [Logback Android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) - Logback port to Android which provides a highly configurable logging framework for Android apps.
- [Punt](https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/punt) - cli tool that makes adb logcat better